# Why I am able to open and close my own question?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

I am not able to upvote or downvote my own post. And it's fact.

This question [Why can I vote to close my own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32600/why-can-i-vote-to-close-my-own-question) gives some idea regarding closing question. If I post a dupe on accident, and someone points it out, and realize my mistake, I can help correct mistake by voting to close my question.

Somewhat true. But what's the benefit for keeping ability to reopen my own question.

Why I am able to open and close my own question?

Comment: It's also useful if you want to migrate your post elsewhere via the off-topic reason.

Comment: Because upvoting and downvoting has nothing to do with closing and re-opening?

Comment: @The Establishment: But it's kind of voting on my own questions which having some value. i.e. 5 votes required to close question. 5 votes to reopen question.

Comment: Please give explanation of site feature while downvoting :P

Comment: +1 because I think it's a valuable question to have available for someone else who wonders why. However, I don't agree with the implication that it is somehow incorrect to enable the OP to vote to close/open their own questions. I'm fairly sure that disagreement explains the current down vote, too.

Comment: I'd like the ability to downvote myself.

Comment: @manishearth. Would we get -3 total for dv'ing our own answers? ;)

Comment: @Manishearth: Me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are conflating the purpose of voting a question with the purpose of *closing* it. They are similar but distinct.

An upvote means that the question is of good quality. A downvote means that it is of low quality. A low quality question may not be subjectively good, but it can still be a legitimate question for the site.

A close vote means "this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow as it is currently stated." A reopen vote means the opposite. Closing is for getting rid of things we don't want; downvoting is for saying that something is or is not good by some subjective standard.

Do we not want to get rid of bad questions? Yes, but what is good and bad are subjective; hence the open voting system. What is and isn't appropriate for SO is a lot more clear-cut than what is good or bad.

Comment: I got purpose of close or reopen. But why this ability of voting given to me? Why it's not totally to community?

Answer (score 8):

The OP may want to vote for closing the question if the question turns out to be an exact duplicate or to belong on a different SE site after all.

The OP may want to vote for reopening the question if the question was initially been closed as "not a real question" and the OP has afterwards edited the question to improve it according the site's rules. *However, flagging for moderator attention often works quicker*.

To name just the most common reasons.

Comment: Is this only reason for giving ability to vote for open and close question? Why it's not totally kept totally to community ( at least for open question)?

Comment: In a democracy, your own vote counts.